# Польза универсальных ссылок

Tags: c++, c++11

Правильно ли я понимаю, что универсальные ссылки хороши тем что захватывают всё подряд(т.е. lvalue and rvalue) и нужны ТОЛЬКО для того, чтобы потом перенаправить через forward в "нужное место"?

Comment: Скорее - верно, что "захватывают все подряд", а уж "только для перенаправления" - не только, вы можете делать с ними, что хотите...

Comment: А для чего ещё можно еще применить универсальную ссылку не в связке с перенаправлением?

Comment: Еще они могут привязываться, к каким-нибудь proxy-объектам. Например, в range-based-for. Ну и "универсальные" ссылки - это те же самые l/rvalue-ссылки, так что их применение точно такое же.